# Is there a way to store data collected from an IOS app directly to Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using Xcode and swift. I am trying to create an app that automates receipt documentation instead of traditionally filling in the information in a spreadsheet.

I have used the vision framework to pull data about the receipt and classify it. I was able to classify the essential information (Price, Date, etc), but I'm struggling with how I can store and display the data in a file.

I have looked into the different databases I could use, but I was wondering if there is a short way to upload this data from the app directly to Google Spreadsheets using swift. In short, even if I will go with the database approach, I would still need to display the data in an Excel or CSV way, and I'm unsure of what would be a good approach for that. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use a spreadsheet as API to fetch and update the data. Please review the below link that might be helpful. 

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sql database but Core Data is very great too if you need to store datas. Specially if you need to sync them with iCloud.
In the past i have always use sql but now i find CoreData just better, more clean and more easy (after some time to learn how to use it).

About CSV you can export your datamodel with this sample of code:

```
// MARK: - Exoprt to CSV
    @IBAction func selectorexport(toCSV sender: Any) {
        let docPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).map(\.path)[0]
        let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: docPath).appendingPathComponent("file.csv").path
        
        let contents = String(repeating: "\0", count: 0)
        
        //fill contents with data in csv format
        // ...
        
        //var error: Error?
        
        do {
            try contents.write(
                toFile: filePath,
                atomically: true,
                encoding: .utf8)
        } catch {
        }
        
        // check for the error
        
        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        
        let activityItems = ["file.csv", fileUrl] as [Any]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        
        if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.barButtonItem = btShare
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
        }
        
        // Present action sheet.
        present(activityViewController, animated: true)
    }
```